# QTableWidgetItem text changed

Tags: c++, qt

Im looking for a clean way to react on the event if a `QTableWidgetItem` has changed its text. I´ve tried to use the Signal `QTableWidget::itemChanged(QTableWidgetItem *item)` but this causes an error due to the fact that i change the backgroundcolor of the `QTableWidgetItem` in my slot and this slot is then executed recursivly, because the itemChanged.

I've also tried to use the signal `QTableWidget::itemEntered(QTableWidgetItem *item)`but this is related to some mouse events which doesnt really work  for me.

The last method I've tried is to override the eventfilter in my custom QTableWidget class like this:

```
    bool custom_DropTable::eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *evt)
{
    if (evt->type() == QEvent::KeyPress)
    {
        QKeyEvent *keyEvent = static_cast<QKeyEvent *>(evt);
        if (keyEvent->key() == Qt::Key_Return)
        {
            emit si_itemTextEntered(this->currentItem());
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return QObject::eventFilter(obj, evt);
    }
}
```

But the signal is never really arrived even if pressed enter so set the text.

Has someone any suggestions or improvements for me?

Comment: When does the text change and who initiates that? You could connect to the `QTableWidgetItem`'s model signal `dataChanged(QModelIndex, QModelIndex)`

Comment: I cannot find this signal in [`QTableWidgetItem`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtablewidgetitem-members.html) list of members.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make your widget no to send signals using [`QObject::blockSignals`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#blockSignals). This way you can use the signal `QTableWidget::itemChanged(QTableWidgetItem* item)` connected to an slot that will first block the signals of the table, then change the item, and then unblock the signals. Here you have a minimum example:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QTableWidget>
#include <QTableWidgetItem>

// Declare table globaly so the slot can block its signals
QTableWidget* table;

// Slot
void itemChanged(QTableWidgetItem* item)
{
  // Block table signals
  table->blockSignals(true);

  // Change item background color
  item->setBackgroundColor(Qt::red);

  // Append text
  item->setText(item->text() + " edited");

  // Unblock signals
  table->blockSignals(false);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  // Create application
  QApplication app(argc, argv);

  // Create table
  table = new QTableWidget(3, 4);

  // Add items
  for (int i = 0; i < table->rowCount() * table->columnCount(); i++)
  {
    int row = i / table->columnCount();
    int col = i % table->columnCount();
    table->setItem(row, col, new QTableWidgetItem(QString::number(i)));
  }

  // Connect
  QObject::connect(table, &QTableWidget::itemChanged, itemChanged);

  // Show table
  table->show();

  // Run
  return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: it worked well ! thanks, i have found also another way with the signal currentItemChanged(QTableWidgetItem*,QTableWidgetItem*). Both worked well for me