# How to get a signal when a user is typing in a cell in qtablewidget? C++

Tags: c++, qtablewidget

QtableWidget emits a signal when a cell is changed but what I need is to know when the user is typing.

For example: if the user write "cat" in a cell, I need to get a signal when is written "c", other signal when is written "a" and another third signal when is written "t". "cellChanged" emits the signal only after lefting the cell.

I tried to use a eventFilter but it is not working unfortunately.

```
bool Matrix::eventFilter(QObject *object, QEvent *event)
{
   if (object == ui->tableWidget && event->type() == QEvent::KeyPress)
   {
      ...
   } 
}
```

I tried with `this->state()==QAbstractItemView::EditingState` but this is a protected member of QAbstractItemView and I do not know how to subclass QTablewidget.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: "it is not working" how? does it not compile or give some runtime error or run OK but just not do anything?

Comment: It runs Ok, but it doesn't entry in this condition 'if (object == ui->tableWidget && event->type() == QEvent::KeyPress)' when I write something in the qtablewidget underscore_d

Comment: Could info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55725078/7644018) possibly help?

Comment: Thank you, but it doens't work for me, because they solve it blocking signals

Comment: @Masa
Any news ? Did you find a solution ?

Comment: @Erel thank you for being attentive. I have some errors that I couldn't solve yet. I am gonna keep trying to implement your solution and I will be back to you as soon as possible

Comment: @Masa
Nevermind. Let me also notify you that I updated my answer below with the `Q_OBJECT` macro that should fix the problem telling you that you cannot put a signal in the class (as I do not know if you noticed it or not).

Answer (score 1):

Not necessarily the best solution, but I would do something as follows.

• Create a subclass of QWidget or whatever fills your `QTableWidget` (for clarification purposes, let us name it `CellWidget`).

• Give this class the `signal`s you want :  `a_signal(someArgument);`, `c_signal(someArgument);`, `t_signal(someArgument);`.
It requires putting the `Q_OBJECT` macro in the class definition.
Assuming you need some properties of both `QTableWidget` and something such as `QLineEdit` (put the latter could be replaced by anything meant to hold text) :

• Override `void QWidget::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event)` as below.

```cpp
class CellWidget : public QTableWidgetItem , public QLineEdit{

    Q_OBJECT

protected :
    
    void keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event) override;
    
public signals :

//Declaration of the signals

}
```

```cpp
void CellWidget::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event){

    switch(event->key()){
        
        case(Qt::Key_A):{
        emit(a_signal(someArgumentWithCorrectType));
        break;
        }
        
        //etc.
        
        default:{break;}

    }

    ParentClass::keyPressEvent(event); //Processes the event as seen from the parent class
    event->accept(); 
}
```

• Fill the table with these widgets and connect them to the appropriate `slot` :

```cpp
for(int i = 0 ; i < table->rowCount() ; i++){
    
    for(int j = 0 ; j < table->columnCount() ; j++){
        
        CellWidget *cw = new CellWidget(table);
        connect(cw , &CellWidget::a_signal , someWidget , &SomeWidget::someSlotA);
        connect(cw , &CellWidget::c_signal , someWidget , &SomeWidget::someSlotC);
        connect(cw , &CellWidget::t_signal , someWidget , &SomeWidget::someSlotT);
        table->setCellWidget(i , j  , cw);
        
    }
    
}
```

You may not specify an argument for the signal, or use this very argument to do some logic in the slot :

```cpp
void SomeWidget::SomeSlot(int key){
    
    
    switch(key){
        
        case(...):{
            ...
            break;
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

You may also check if the CellWidget is in focus in the event (look at `QWiget::hasFocus()`).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I use many functionalities of Qtablewidgetitem, I hope I can find other solution without needing to create a subclass of QWidget. But if I don't find other solution I would apply your approach

Comment: Why not put `CellWidget` as subclass of both `QWidget` (or `QLineEdit` or anything meant to hold text) AND `QTableWidgetItem` ? Using this approach (double inheritance), you may even solve the problems you had in your other questions by overriding the appropriate event handler.

Comment: Thank you again! I tried to apply your recommendation but I am getting the following error: static assertion failed: No Q_OBJECT in the class with the signal
         Q_STATIC_ASSERT_X(QtPrivate::HasQ_OBJECT_Macro<typename SignalType::Object>::Value,
         ^

Comment: If I am not mistaken, you have to add the `Q_OBJECT` macro in your class do be able to assign signals and slots to it. 
I updated my answer to add the class declaration.